# IIS 7.0 Creating self signed certificates with comman name

Tags: iis-7

I am facing an problem when creating a self signed certificate with common name.

System: Windows Server 2008, 64 bit machine, framework 3.5, IIS 7
Tools used: Selfssl7 to create an certificate with common name

Commands used:

```
SelfSSL7 /Q /T /I "Default Web SIte" /N:CN="GamecardRoot"/V:2000 /S:1 /K 2048 /V 3456 /p:443
SelfSSL7 /I "Default Web SIte" /N:CN="GamecardRoot"/V:2000 /S:1 /K 2048 /V 3456 /p:443
```

It does not create a certifcate with a comman name what i have used :GamecardRoot it creates an certficate with system name like :"Sontrx09"

```
Name            Issuedby              Issuedby   
Sontrx09        Sontrx09             Sontrx09
```

Reference used:http://www.kevinlabranche.com/blog/SelfSSLOnIIS7.aspx